# How to insert CSV file into elasticsearch without using Logstash or kibana?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I need some help. I want to insert a large csv file into elasticsearch using Java, is there any plugin regarding the same?. As inserting data manually would be tideous using curl, is there any appropriate way to handle this situation?
Please guide!
P.S I've already tried inserting csv file into Kibana
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the [java rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.8/index.html), you will need to write a program to read your csv file, parse the fields to create a json document and then index it in elasticsearch. If you don't want or don't need to parse your columns into fields, you can just read the lines and index then into elasticsearch. Why not use logstash?

Comment: thanks @leandrojmp for the quick reply, we are building a search utility for concepts in csv so we are using java for implementation for the utility